# Python. Creating a table from a 2D array with numbered rows

Tags: python, arrays

```
t = [[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], [2, 4, 6, 8, 
i = 0
a = 0

for i in range(len(t)):
    for a in range(len(t[i])):
        print(a+1, t[i][a], end=' ')
    print('\n', end='')
```

My expected output would be (in more general terms):

```
a+1     t[i][a] t[i]+[a+2]...
a+2     t[i+1][a]...
```

and so on.

For example (with 2D-array t):

```
1   1 2 3 4 5 6
2   2 4 6 8 10 12
```

Instead with the above code I get:

```
1 1 2 2 3 3 4 4 5 5 6 6 
1 2 2 4 3 6 4 8 5 10 6 12
```

And I cannot pinpoint exactly why. Any ideas?

Comment: In your output format, do you mean `**i**+1     t[i][a] t[i]+[a+**1**]...`?

Comment: Oh my, that's what you get for not getting your coffee for the day. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a small mistake, as you print `a+1` inside the inner loop. You should print `i+1` inside the outer loop.

```
for i, _ in enumerate(t):
    print(i+1, end=' ');
    for a, _ in enumerate(t[i]):
        print(t[i][a], end=' ')
    print('\n', end='')
```

Comment: `a` is not defined there. OP wants `i`.

Comment: Might as well use the values from `enumerate`.

Comment: Thank you, this together with Alex' comment about using i solved my problem.